# Protractor click() is not working as expected, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

Given: Protractor Test with this html and js code.  Was able to do browser.get and click on link to get to log on page successfully.  The Log In form requires a userid and password which was entered correctly from the test, but I can't click the button.

```
<button type="submit" class="button positive">Log In</button>

element.all(by.buttonText('Log In')).then(function (item) {
    item.forEach(function (final) {
        final.submit();  
        final.click();                                              
    });
```

If I put a break point on the ForEach statement I see that 'item' is indeed an array with a length of 1.  It I then break at 'final.submit();' I see this..

[image]

I even tried to submit the form instead of zeroing in on the button...

```
    var af = element.all(by.name('loginForm'));
        af.submit();
    });
```

Results were the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of this problem was that the content of the form submission was wrong.  This was only able to be seen by looking a network level response on the form submission, in essence, the click was working, it's just that the page did nothing.  The developers of the login form didn't expose any login errors in the application.

So I looked into how to get the http response code using protractor and it's not supported because the Selenium team has decided it's not a part of the plan.  Therefore, from a Protractor perspective, your only alternative is to put in the proper expect statement and fail the test if it doesn't 'get there'.

I also was able to determine that the screen shot above was the structure of the Seleneium WebElement class.  Because Selenium is Asynchronous only, what is seen above is only the methods as it is the promise that returns the results of the properties and or the function calls.